# calling button class in a form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am herewith develop an application but I have created a class which calls button events(i.e. enable or visible)

```html
Public Class ClassfrmLoad

    Dim btnAdd As New Button
    Dim btnEdit As New Button
   
    Private Sub FormLoad()

        Me.btnAdd.Visible = True
        Me.btnAdd.Enabled = True

        Me.btnEdit.Visible = True
        Me.btnEdit.Enabled = False

    End Sub

End Class
```

I am actually created the button events class(classfrmLoad) for the way which buttons should be enabled and visible when each & every form loading.

There are 6 buttons in the forms (frm1, frm2 etc.,) like btnAdd, btnEdit, btnCancel etc., i don't want to display the buttons(visible/enable) while loading the form.

Here is the question:
How can i call this class(classfrmLoad) events to alter (enable/visible) the buttons positioned in the forms(frm1, frm2, etc.,) and how to get the buttons events in those forms?

Dear Sergio,

Thanks for your immediate response. I am missing something and it is not as expected, here is my complete code for the form including yours.

This is the code you suggested for the classfrmLoad:

```html
Public Class ClassfrmLoad

    Public Shared Sub FormLoad(ByRef Target As Form)

        For Each ctl As Control In Target.Controls
            If Not TypeOf ctl Is Button Then Continue For

            Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(ctl, Button)

            Select Case btn.Name.ToLower()

                Case "btnadd"
                    btn.Visible = True
                    btn.Enabled = True

                Case "btnsave"
                    btn.Visible = False
                    btn.Enabled = False

                Case "btnedit"
                    btn.Visible = True
                    btn.Enabled = True

                Case "btncancel"
                    btn.Visible = True
                    btn.Enabled = False

                Case "btnclose"
                    btn.Visible = True
                    btn.Enabled = True

                Case "btnupdate"
                    btn.Visible = False
                    btn.Enabled = False

                Case "btnfind"
                    btn.Visible = False
                    btn.Enabled = False

                    'and so on
            End Select
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

This is the code for the formload event:

```html
 Private Sub frmCreate_Unit_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ClassfrmLoad.FormLoad(Me)


        'Display software and title of the page
        Me.Text = msgCap & " | " & " CREATE UNIT"
        Me.lblComp.Text = CompName

        Me.stBar_User.Text = frmMain.stBar_User.Text
        Me.stBar_UserID.Text = frmMain.stBar_UserID.Text
        Me.stBar_G_ID.Text = frmMain.stBar_G_ID.Text
        Me.stBar_G_No.Text = frmMain.stBar_G_No.Text



        Me.cboUnit.Visible = False
        Me.txtUnit_Long.Visible = True

        Me.btnfind.Visible = False
        Me.txtUnit_ID.Enabled = False

        Me.btnadd.Focus()

    End Sub
```

Please help me to sort out this one. Thanks...

Comment: Unclear without further detail and some source code.

Comment: You don't "call" classes... you access it's members by invoking methods or properties. Perhaps you meant to ask how do you programatically invoke a button handler?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.
Sorry, i still don't get it. Why would you create a class instance at form load just to change button's visibility?
Why not just changing it on the form load handler itself?

Comment: Because there is lot of forms and lot of classes like (clAdd, clEdit, clSave, etc). It is so simple if I written in one place and calling every place of need.

Comment: Ok, i got it now. I'll write an answer

Comment: What is the "not expected" bit? Is there any error?
Note that you're affecting btnFind **after** the ClassfrmLoad method invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Every form in WinForms is a class instance, inherited from Form class.
Because of this, you cannot make static references to it's members from another class, given any Form instance.
Generic class won't cut it either because you're after specific class members.
I would take advantage of the Controls collection and would check it's name and type. Once caught, we can cast the control to button and set it's visibility and access.

For this, you should make small adjustments to your code:

```
Public Class ClassfrmLoad

    Public Shared Sub FormLoad(ByRef Target As Form)

        For Each ctl As Control In Target.Controls
            If Not TypeOf ctl Is Button Then Continue For
            Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(ctl, Button)
            Select Case btn.Name.ToLower()
                Case "btnadd", "btnedit"
                    btn.Visible = True
                    btn.Enabled = True
                    'and so on
            End Select
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

- Changed the FormLoad visibility and access. It should be shared so we don't need to create unnecessary instances of this class
- Added a parameter, passe **by reference** that referrs the target form. This will assure that you can use it on any class that inherits Form class
- Iterated the Controls collection and find a candidate based on it's type and name
- When found, we cast it to Button and access it's properties normally.

It's just an example, based on your code.

You should now call it on every Form's formload handler, like so:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ClassfrmLoad.FormLoad(Me)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution. It is very simple and any way thanks to sergio.
Here is the complete code.

Public Class ClassfrmLoad

```
Public Shared Sub formLoad(ByVal btnAdd As Button, ByVal btnEdit As Button, ByVal btnSave As Button, ByVal btnCancel As Button, ByVal btnClose As Button, ByVal btnUpdate As Button, ByVal btnFind As Button)


    btnAdd.Visible = True
    btnAdd.Enabled = True

    btnSave.Visible = False
    btnSave.Enabled = False

    btnCancel.Visible = True
    btnCancel.Enabled = False

    btnClose.Visible = True
    btnClose.Enabled = True

    btnEdit.Visible = True
    btnEdit.Enabled = True

    btnUpdate.Visible = False
    btnUpdate.Enabled = False

    btnFind.Visible = False
    btnFind.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

End Class

And calling proceedure in a form like this:

Dim x As New ClassfrmLoad
        ClassfrmLoad.formLoad(Me.btnAdd, Me.btnEdit, Me.btnSave, Me.btnCancel, Me.btnClose, Me.btnUpdate, Me.btnFind)